# Parallel processing of splitting and joining of images using Python

Tags: python, multithreading, image-processing, multiprocessing

I am trying to split an image in to 4 and then process it and then join them parallelly.(I was able to do this serially).

I am here using Image_slicer library for slice and join functions.
Also, trying to work on these slice tiles parallelly during which 4 processes are created and started. The processed tile is replaced on the original sliced paths. But, when I try to join them it does not work because all the processing is done in an external function and their local parameters does not retain them anymore.
Is there any way I could do this??

Please find my code below:

```
from image_slicer import slice,join
from multiprocessing import Process
import cv2

tiles=slice('test.jpeg',4)

def getting_image(image_path): 
    img_todraw_defects = cv2.imread(image_path)
    blur= cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(img_todraw_defects,21,49)
    gray_image= cv2.cvtColor(blur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imwrite(image_path,gray_image)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    processes = []

    for i in tiles:
        p = Process(target=getting_image, args=(i.filename,))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    for process in processes:
        process.join()

Final=join(tiles)
Final.save('final.png')
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use `Shared Memory` or the `Manager` class from the `multiprocessing`package to share data between processes. [Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#sharing-state-between-processes).

Comment: I tried to run your provided code to see what can be done. But I found that even in serial execution of the `getting_image(image_path)` function the final image was unchanged. There seems to be something else wrong. Since you write the changed files to disk to the same filename your code above should assemble the changed figure. To me it does not seem to be a multiprocessing issue. Could you provide your working serial version of the code.

Comment: Thanks for responding...It works now with the help of Queue..I returned the address to the calling function.

Comment: i wanted to run this on GPU but somehow it does not reduce much of computation time